# ElasticSearch TransportClient version 5.6

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm new in Elastisearch Java API

I installed the version 5.6 My server elasticsearch is runing in

http://localhost:9200/

```
 {
      "name" : "KJj0iv3",
      "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
      "cluster_uuid" : "0je2mMloQ52X_GT1itxGuA",
      "version" : {
        "number" : "5.6.3",
        "build_hash" : "1a2f265",
        "build_date" : "2017-10-06T20:33:39.012Z",
        "build_snapshot" : false,
        "lucene_version" : "6.6.1"
      },
      "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
    }
```

and this is my class Test Java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
    try {
        TransportClient client;

        client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9200));
        // on shutdown
        client.close();
    } catch (ElasticsearchException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

this is my error

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger.debug(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool.<init>(ThreadPool.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:129)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:265)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:130)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:116)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:106)
    at queryDsl.Test.main(Test.java:24)
```

Comment: What are the dependencies of your project ?

Comment: <dependency>
     <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
     <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
     <version>5.6.3</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: have you tried to set up a log4j2 config file (for example log4j2.xml file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use port 9300 instead on 9200 as [TransportClient](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html) needs port 9300 as it communicates using the transport module.