# How to create a TransportClient object in elasticsearch 6.3.0

Tags: scala, elasticsearch

I am trying to migrate from a very old version of elasticsearch to the latest version 6.3.0. I have found this link [ElasticSearch TransportClient version 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078492/elasticsearch-transportclient-version-5-6) that shows a pattern that I tried to implement but I can't get it to work:

```
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient

trait ElasticSearchClient {
    lazy val client: TransportClient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(
    Settings.builder()
        .put("cluster.name", clusterName)
        // etc...
        .build())
```

I get the error:

```
[error] object client is not a member of package org.elasticsearch.transport
[error]  import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient
[error]                                     ^
```

I've tried the alternate `import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.PreBuiltTransportClient` but still not resolving.

If I try `lazy val client: TransportClient = new TransportClient(` it says `class TransportClient is abstract; cannot be instantiated`.

If I try `lazy val client: TransportClient = TransportClient.builder().` it says `value builder is not a member of object org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient`.

I cannot find any other documentation or posts on this and I am asking what is the correct pattern to create a `TransportClient` object?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the above works if you add to the libraryDependencies of your build.sbt file:

```
"org.elasticsearch.client" % "transport" % "6.3.0"
```

Note that TransportClient is to be deprecated in 7.0 and removed in 8.0. Use RestClient instead.